# How can I open DevTools and take printscreen in Chrome using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, devtools, printscreen

I use Ruby-Capybara-Cucumber for automated testing, I wonder if it's possible to open DevTools and take printscreen from the console? Thanks.